# Magento 2 Unable to fetch custom options from order item on sales order view page

Tags: magento2, sales-order, custom-options

**sales_order_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="default_order_items_renderer">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**default.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php /** @var \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Items\Renderer\DefaultRenderer $block */ ?>
<?php $_item = $block->getItem() ?>
<?php $block->setPriceDataObject($_item) ?>
<tr>
    <?php $i = 0;
    $columns = $block->getColumns();
    $lastItemNumber = count($columns) ?>
    <?php foreach ($columns as $columnName => $columnClass):?>
        <?php $i++; ?>
        <td class="<?= /* @noEscape */ $columnClass ?><?= /* @noEscape */ ($i === $lastItemNumber ? ' last' : '') ?>"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getColumnHtml($_item, $columnName) ?>
            <?php if($columnClass == "col-product"){  ?>
                <span><?php echo __("Type:") ?></span>
                <?php
                 //here I'm getting empty array 
                 print_r( $_item->getOptionByCode('additional_options'));

                ?>
            <?php  } ?>
        </td>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</tr>
```

`$_item->getOptionByCode('additional_options')` this lines returns empty array .Please someone guide me hoe to get the additional option value .I have seen the `quote_item_option` table it contains the data .
I have added custom options to quote item using below code

```
        $quote = $this->quoteFactory->create()->load($quoteId);
        $_product = $this->product->load($productId);
        $additionalOptions = array();
            if ($additionalOption = $_product->getOptionByCode('additional_options')) {
                $additionalOptions = $this->serializer->unserialize($additionalOption->getValue());
            }

            $additionalOptions[] = [
                'label' => 'Type',
                'value' => 'Sample'
            ];
        $quote->addProduct($_product, 1)
                    ->addOption(array(
                        'product_id' => $_product->getId(),
                        'code' => 'additional_options',
                        'value' => $this->serializer->serialize($additionalOptions)
                    ))
                    ->setCustomPrice(2)
                    ->setWeight(5)
                    ->setOriginalCustomPrice(2)
                    ->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
                $quote->collectTotals()->save();
```

it is adding the item and to quote.After saving the order I tried to get the additional option value but i'm unable to get it on order details page

Comment: as you are manually adding item to quote you need to add it in order too

Comment: but how??can you please share it

Comment: You need to add a plugin please visit this link
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/178386/how-to-add-custom-option-in-quote-or-order-item

Comment: ok i'll try it.

Comment: this is working for me please post it as answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to create a plugin for the retrieve custom option from the cart to order.

First We need to create di.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem">
        <plugin name="unique_name" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Plugin\Quote\ToOrderItem" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Once you have created this file, now you need to create another file and named as CompanyName\ModuleName\Model\Plugin\Quote\ToOrderItem.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Plugin\Quote;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem as QuoteToOrderItem;
use Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json;
class ToOrderItem
{    
    public function __construct(Json $serializer = null) 
    {        
        $this->serializer = $serializer ?: \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->get(\Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json::class);
    }

    public function aroundConvert(QuoteToOrderItem $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $item,
        $data = []
    ) {
        // Get Order Item
        $orderItem = $proceed($item, $data);               
                
        $additionalOptions = $item->getOptionByCode('additional_options');        
        // Check if there is any additional options in Quote Item                    
        if (count($additionalOptions) > 0) {
            // Get Order Item's other options
            $options = $orderItem->getProductOptions();
            // Set additional options to Order Item
            $options['additional_options'] = $this->serializer->unserialize($additionalOptions->getValue());
            $orderItem->setProductOptions($options);
        }
 
        return $orderItem;
    }
}
```